# WScript.Shell SendKeys not working on Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: windows, vbscript, wsh

I'm having problems with the following VBScript.

I'm trying to send keystrokes to a web browser window, but nothing happens.

The first two lines in the following script works fine, but the third line with the `SendKeys` command, doesn't do anything.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "http://someurl.com", 1
objShell.SendKeys "Some Text"
```

I've tried to run the script on two different Win 8.1 machines. On Win 8.1 Pro it works, but on Win 8.1 not-Pro it won't work. Is there any setting somewhere in Windows that needs to be set or anything other that can help me?

**Update**

New code tried (added sleep and running browser explicit), but still no luck

```
Set ObjShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run """C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe""http://someurl.com/"
WScript.Sleep 5000
objShell.SendKeys "Some Text"
```

Answer (score 0):

While its admittedly not a great programming technique, place a *Sleep* command after your *objShell.Run* line (as shown below) to give the OS some time to "catch up" and actually run the URL, activate the browser window to give it focus (you have to take note of the title in the Browser window and use that title exactly), because I have seen the browser window lose focus in some cases and then text cannot be piped into it, and finally it sends the text.   Your mileage may vary, and you might even have to increase the sleep time in order to be successful.  I've had to sleep up to 30 seconds, in some cases. Especially where, for whatever reason, the web page was slow to render - due to network latency, slow OS, etc..  I haven't faced this problem on Windows 8.1 because I haven't tried it on that platform.  I don't think this has anything to do with the OS version; I have faced this same problem with *SendKeys* on other Windows OS versions where I've had to use the *Sleep* function like this.  The *SendKeys* method has known limitations, and as it runs outside of the browser you have to wait for certain actions to complete before you can have it do more actions.

```
Set ObjShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "http://someurl.com", 1
WScript.Sleep 20000
objShell.appactivate("Welcome to SOMEURL.COM! - Mozilla Firefox")
WScript.Sleep 700
objShell.SendKeys "Some Text"
```

Also, you might try replacing line 2 in the above to the following, to see if you have better luck. In the example below, Firefox is the default web browser. Change the path accordingly to the browser of your choice:

`objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe""http://someurl.com")`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have tried sleeping for up to 15 seconds, but with no luck.

Comment: I've had to sleep up to 30 seconds, in some cases.  Especially where, for whatever reason, the web page was slow to render (due to network latency, slow OS, etc...)

Comment: Also, try replacing line 2 to the following, to see if you have better luck, in this example, Firefox is the default web browser; change the path accordingly to the browser of your choice:  _objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe""http://someurl.com/")_

Comment: I've just added/incorporated all my edits into the Answer I gave earlier, for better readability.

Comment: It's missing a space after `firefox.exe""`. As it stands it will run like this `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"http://someurl.com`.

Comment: @Lankymart, good eyes, but it might not run if you put a space there like that.  I just tested both with the space and without it - but only on Windows XP.  Since OP is talking about Windows 8.1 which I don't have handy to test, you could be correct.  At least on Windows XP, if you put a space in that position, it won't run.

Comment: Don't really use FF so hard to test but having no space seems wrong to me would `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "http://someurl.com"` not work? Which in the code would be `"""C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"" ""http://someurl.com"""`.

Comment: @Lankymart, I agree it doesn't look right but I use a number of these SendKeys scripts and none of them have a space right there in that spot.  Looking forward to the OP responding, and seeing who's right.  :-)

Comment: It may work, but doesn't mean it should stay like that if you check the [FF documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-browser) the `-url` switch clearly shows a space between program and url. It would definitely fail with multiple urls.

Comment: Unfortunately none of your fine suggestions worked. The browser opens and navigates to the correct URL, but the SendKeys command doesn't do anything. Sleeping for 15 seconds doesn't help (the web site is fully loaded). I've also tried a Powershell solution, but got stuck at the same point.

Comment: I've thought more about this and edited my answer to add an in-line comment regarding activating the browser window in order for text to be successfully piped into it.  I've seen it loses focus in some cases and that may be what is happening in your case.

Comment: Good suggestion, but still no luck. The window isn't losing focus. the script opens the browser window, the first input field gets focus by default/code, the script waits and the nothing happens. When the wait is over the caret in the input field stops blinking, indicating that something is happening, but nothing actually happens on the screen. If I begin typing manually, the text gets in the input field.